# Ruby- split last three fields

Tags: ruby, split

I know split is a useful tool and I know there is a way to do this.  I tried a few different methods but couldn't figure it out via google. Can anyone help me.

```
example1 = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5"
example2 = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7"
```

So I need the result to look like this

```
example1 = test3,test4,test5
example2 = test5,test6,test7
```

I would like to keep the comma's too.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: What did you try, knowing `String#split` method?

Comment: Just `split` and then `join` the last three elements of each array. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically just `split` and `join` on commas. Negative indexes into an array will easily get you the last however-many elements. So I think you want `str.split(',')[-3..-1].join(',')`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! The part I didn't know was that I could just do [-3..-1]

Answer (score 4):

```
example = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5"
example.split(',')[-3..-1] # => [test3,test4,test5]
```

Split gives you an array. You can use ranges to select subsets of an array. The negative numbers are counting from the end of the array, so `[-3..-1]` selects the third last to the last element.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `last(3)` instead of `[-3..-1]`, like this:

```
example = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5"
example.split(',').last(3).join(',') # => "test3,test4,test5"
```